# Chi Square Test of Independence in Python

Tags: python, r, numpy, statistics, scipy

Under Ubuntu 10.04.4, using Python 2.6.5, NumPy and SciPy, is it possible to do a chi square test of independence? In `R`, this is [achieved](http://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/independ.html) with the following:

```
> row1 = c(91,90,51)
> row2 = c(150,200,155)
> row3 = c(109,198,172)
> data.table = rbind(row1,row2,row3)
> chisq.test(data.table)
```

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: @larsmans: No, I don't think it's a duplicate. This is a different test, using `chi2_contingency`. That question uses observed and expected values.

Comment: Please note that this is not a duplicate, as I indicated in the note above, as different chi square tests are involved.

Comment: This question was wrongly made a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency

row1 = [91,90,51]
row2 = [150,200,155]
row3 = [109,198,172]
data=[row1,row2,row3]
print chi2_contingency(data)
```

Output:

```
(25.085973274234959, 4.8346447416999636e-05, 4, array([[  66.77631579,   93.10526316,   72.11842105],
       [ 145.35361842,  202.66447368,  156.98190789],
       [ 137.87006579,  192.23026316,  148.89967105]]))
```

R Output:

```
        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  data.table 
X-squared = 25.086, df = 4, p-value = 4.835e-05
```

Comment: SciPy in Ubuntu 10.04.4 does not have `chi2_contingency`. Using `import scipy.stats` in Kubuntu 13.10 works, though. The line starting `chi2` does not work, however.

Comment: what's the version of scipy you are using? Mine is '0.10.1'.

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 is several years old, and SciPy development proceeds pretty quickly.

Comment: @larsmans: Yes; I figured that it is not possible to do this using Ubuntu 10.04.4.

Comment: @VIKASHJAISWAL: It's 0.7-something under Ubuntu 10.04.4 and 0.12.0 under Kubuntu 13.10.

Comment: yes, in 0.7 i don't see chi2_contingency, you can have a look at documentation here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.7.x/reference/stats.html